# Event ID 41, 6008 nog logged after a power loss

Tags: event-log

For what reasons a Windows server (2003) will not log an event ID 41, 6008 if it did indeed had a power loss?

Comment: What events DOES the server log for those outages?

Comment: "The previous system shutdown at ... on ... was unexpected"

Comment: A) all information like this must be added to the original question, making it more complete and clear. B) that means you probably have a hardware problem. If the OS can't capture a fault, it's the hardware that's likely at fault.